# How can i change tabbar titlecolor runtime in iOS 13?

Tags: swift, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, ios13, tabbar

In my application, I want to change tab bar title color and icon color when theme change on button click in iOS 13.

I set basic tabbar color in viewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let appearance = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .red
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .blue
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance

}
```

When clicking on the button I want to change tab bar appearance but it is not working.

```
@IBAction func changeTabbarApperence(){

    let appearance = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .green
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .orange
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange]
    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance

}
```

Can anyone help me to implement this functionality? How can I change the tab bar appearance runtime?